# Basis and dimension of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Let $V=\{f : S \to \mathbb{R} \}$ be the set of all the functions $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $S=\{ 1,2,...,n$}, now my train of thought was that the basis of V must be a linearly independent set that Span V so somehow show that there is a set of functions on *S* that can compose as a linear combination and map to any number in $\mathbb{R}$. Any idea how to get a general answer for basis for dimension of *V*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $f_i\in V\;(i=1,\ldots, n)$ such that $f_i(j)=\delta_{ij}$, that is:

$$f_1\equiv\begin{cases}f_1(1)=1\\
f_1(2)=0\\
\ldots\\
f_1(n)=0\end{cases}\quad f_2\equiv\begin{cases}f_2(1)=0\\
f_2(2)=1\\
\ldots\\
f_2(n)=0\end{cases}\quad\ldots\quad f_n\equiv\begin{cases}f_n(1)=0\\
f_n(2)=0\\
\ldots\\
f_n(n)=1.\end{cases}$$ We can easily prove that $B=\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}\subset V$ is a basis of $V.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, V is simply $\mathbf R^n$. Do you know how to characterise families of vectors which are a basis of  $\mathbf R^n$?

Comment: Are you asking about qualities that make a family of vectors a basis? In that case yes, but I'm understanding how to get a general/concrete answer without it sounding like I am making this basis up.

Comment: Isn't the determinant criterion a concrete answer?